# Replacing DLL in Windows Installer Project

Tags: c#, vsto, windows-installer

I have a Windows Installer project built for my VSTO add-in.  However, I have to run one of my DLLs through an obfuscator at the end, but if I try to build the setup project with the modified DLL, it just rebuilds my original DLL and overwrites the modified one.  Is there a way I can build the setup project and use my modified DLL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you simply add the DLL to your installer project the way you'd add a static file?  Treat it as 'content'.

Comment: This is working a bit.  I've got to do more checking to make sure though.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run the obfuscator in your post-build event:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Release <obfuscatorprogram> $(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)
```

Post-build events are in your project properties, under Build Events.

if you're already doing this, I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Hi HiredMind.  For some reason I still can't get that to work.  What I did was build my program's DLL (this is still in Debug release mode), and then have a pre build event that compies the obfuscated DLL to the build folder before build (I also did a post build event).  For some reason the assembly being packaged is still not obfuscated.  Any other ideas?